# PrimeFaces: What is the default value of process attribute on CommandButton or CommandLink?

Tags: primefaces, process, default, partial

What is the default value of `process` attribute on `commandButton` or `commandLink` components? I mean if I specify only `partialSubmit="true"` but do not write the `process` attribute altogether, what will be used to process? Will it be `@all`, `@form` or `@none`?

Thanks, 
Kunal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It will be `@all` if I do not specify `process` attribute but write `partialSubmit="true"`.

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: Can you please add a reference/source to your answer?

Comment: @MathieuCastets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces

Comment: @MathieuCastets I debugged the Ajax request using Chrome Debugger to find that it adds `all` to the Ajax request.